# Extract certain string pattern from a string

Tags: php, javascript

Let said i have :

```
var text1 = "James<>Australia";
```

I want to extract James and Australia and store it in as array just as below

```
extractedText[0] = "james";
extractedText[1] = "Australia";
```

How do i do that?

In php, i use :

```
$extractedText = preg_split("/<>/",$text1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need regular expressions for such a split:

```
$parts = explode('<>', $text1);
```

In JavaScript that translates to:

```
var parts = text1.split('<>');
```

Comment: Hey mate, I was first and you got whole credit... but let it be :)

Comment: @Carlos My answer is not the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

What about `split` function?

```
text1.split(/<>/);
```

Or paste it directly to JS console to check the result:

```
"James<>Australia".split(/<>/);
```

I think it will work exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text1 = "James<>Australia";
var extractedText = text1.split(/<>/);
```